# writing python dict data to CSV file

Tags: python, csv

i am writing the python dict to CSV file by using the following code.

```
my_dict['date'] = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
my_dict['error_log'] =  data
file_exists = os.path.isfile('build_error_deatils.csv')
with open('build_error_deatils.csv', 'a+') as f:
w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
   if not file_exists:
       w.writeheader()
w.writerow(my_dict)
```

everything getting copy properly apart from a chunk of log data which is the string like below.

```
 data = """
../../../../../../../src/junos/usr.sbin/l2cpd/os/l2cpd_rts_reader.c: In function 'l2cpd_vpls_iff_get_stp_index':
../../../../../../../src/junos/usr.sbin/l2cpd/os/l2cpd_rts_reader.c:129: error: 'RTM_IFF_RLT_ACTIVE_LINK' undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../../../../../src/junos/usr.sbin/l2cpd/os/l2cpd_rts_reader.c:129: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
../../../../../../../src/junos/usr.sbin/l2cpd/os/l2cpd_rts_reader.c:129: error: for each function it appears in.)
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
../../../../../../../src/junos/usr.sbin/l2cpd/os/l2cpd_rts_reader.c:129: warning: unused variable 'addi'
make[1]: *** [l2cpd_rts_reader.o] Error 1
***

"""
 my_dict['error_log'] =  data
```

i am getting the data like below.

[image]

not sure why error log is coming as empty.
need help here thankyou in advance...

Comment: When viewing it, try dragging the row height down. You have a newline as your first character so it might be there but not visible.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinEvans, but this is not the case here

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to resolve this by changing the string to raw string.

```
my_dict['error_log'] = repr(data)
```